Retaining types during numpy operations
Disclaimer: I already posted this on Reddit so apologies if it’s just reaching the same community
Hi Everyone, I having real trouble retaining the numpy array types under operations. I have defined the following type:
BatchNactionsNpFloatType = Annotated[np.ndarray[tuple[int,int], np.float32], Literal["batch", "n_actions"]]

I have two arrays defined with this type e.g.:
x:BatchNactionsNpFloatType = np.array([[1.0,2.0],[1.0,3.0],[1.0,2.0],[1.0,2.0]])
y:BatchNactionsNpFloatType = np.array([[1.0,2.0],[1.0,2.0],[3.0,2.0],[1.0,2.0]])

And I perform a simple operation:
res = np.equal(x,y)

However,  according to VS code, 'res' is of type Any. I'm really confused why it wouldn't return something like np.ndarray[np.bool_]?
Thanks!
I was expecting the np.equal operation to return an ndarray bool type
Update 02/05/2024
As suggested I have added a vscode flag however, I am not convinced this is a vscode issue since MyPy equally fails to assert that np.equal(x,y) is an array. Rather it thinks it is Any as it does not flag even incorrect methods.
Cheers

i've updated this with the python tag, please use the generic python tag for all python related questions

res is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>; res[0] is [True  True] <class 'numpy.ndarray'>; res[0,0] is True <class 'numpy.bool_'>

Hey - thanks for the response! That’s not what the VS code type checking is telling me though - it’s saying res is Any.

That's a VSCode issue then.

add a vscode tag

So, MyPy raises an error of: Expression type contains "Any" (has type "ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]]"). Given the result will be an array of booleans, and I retain the shape of the input arrays, is there no way to carry this information in the type?
